# Trigger a URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need a script that triggers a URL(go to the URL and that's it).

What's the shortest way to write this script?

Comment: Do you mean "takes the user to the URL in the browser", or "silently fires a GET request to the URL"?

Comment: Silently. That's why I said using Ajax. The user would stay on the same page while the browser fires a request to another page. The result from that request is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample AJAX code sample that can be used to fire a silent query to the browser and fetch the response and act on it.

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // Do something with the result, like post a notification
        $('#notice').html('<p class="success">'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</p>');
    }
}

xmlhttp.open('GET',url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).

```
window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

Or shorter (not recommend though).

```
location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

No ajaxical magic needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location='http://www.google.com';
```

Of course you could code-golf out the url and the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks:
Use window.location.

window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.